# Good DNS Hosting

Tags: web-hosting, dns, nameserver

We look after about 50 websites for clients on shared hosting. We'll soon be moving them to a dedicated server so I am looking for a good place to manage my DNS records (the shared server is currently used as the nameserver too). I want something more reliable.

I found DynDNS and was looking at their [Small to Medium Business offering](http://www.dyndns.com/services/dynectsmb/), does anyone have experience of using them? Also I presume '100 records' means 100 A records, CNAMES etc, not 100 different domains (my DNS knowledge is very limited).

Can anyone suggest a good provider for a design/web agency that manages the hosting for it's clients?

Thanks

Ric

Comment: You are right, the Zones will be the actual number of domains you can host while the records are within those zones. For example: Adding a sub domain to a zone will count as one extra record. For the number of clients you have, you would have to go with the Dynect SMB 50 package.

Comment: @Digital Essence. Thanks, looks like I would be right on the limit of the SMB package :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My votes with an oldie but a goodie - http://dyn.com/enterprise-dns/dynect-platform

Answer (score 0):

http://www.internet.bs is quite a good